# What is the replacement for `--net=container` in new docker networking?

Tags: networking, docker

In the pre docker 1.9 days I used to have a vpn provider container which I could use as the network gateway for my other containers by passing the option `--net=container:[container-name]`.

This was very simple but had a major limitation in that the provider container had to exist prior to starting the consumers and it could not be restarted.

The new docker networking stack seems to have dropped this provision in favour of creating networks which does sound better, but I'm struggling to get equivalent behaviour.

Right now I have created an internal network `docker network create isolated --internal --subnet=172.32.0.0/16` and brought up 2 containers one of which is attached only to internal network and one which is attached to both the default bridge and the internal network.

Now I need to route all network traffic from the isolated container through the connected one. I've messed around with some iptable rules but tbh this is not my strongest area.

So my questions are simply: Is my approach along the right lines? What rules need to be in place in the two containers to get this working as `--net=container`?

Comment: Why not just continue using `--net=container`? That is still fully supported with Docker 1.12.1, even when using custom networks.

Comment: Interesting. In my testing yesterday it seemed that custom networks were not compatible with this, I'll certainly take another look at that as could be human error. Thanks.

Comment: In nay case I know I *can* still use this feature but it has all the original drawbacks whereas a custom network solution seems to promise so much more. Certainly not a blocker but it would be cool to do this in a way that didn't require containers to be started in a specific order and was more tolerant of the parent container disappearing.